# Temporary bypass for Wordpress Theme Registration

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Need to deliver a workable website to client by tomorrow and need to temporarily bypass registration for a nulled wordpress theme until their marketing department can get me the Themeforest Purchase code tomorrow.

Basically, marketing intern bought BeTheme (which I requested), and then went AWOL without giving me purchase code. Now she can't find it and refuses to send me ThemeForest login.  I'll be on-site tomorrow and can get the code and get the theme registered properly tomorrow, but until then, I need to bypass/crack the registration so everything is updated and good to go for launch tomorrow morning.

I've dug through the theme's source code and tried to figure out what connection is being made to check for registration, but having trouble.  Can anyone help?

Comment: So been playing around in admin directory, where I found the process for checking site registration and setting ID as registered, unregistered, etc.

I got it to the point where it gives me a "Registration success" message when I submit the purchase code as blank, but even after that, everything else displays the "please register" notices

Answer (score 0):

if i am to get you right, you have a nulled wordpress theme, and its kinda showing you to register the theme, and then be able to use it / customize it till the site owner give you the main purchased theme.

1. its infragmentation of copyright law and license.
2. if you still want to go ahead, you need to know the technology/ plugin the theme author used in locking the theme till user place registration code, ACF, optin theme, SMOF or redux frame work, or better still a self built theme option, figure that out and you are close to the money.

if this isn't your answer please share a screen shoot or make me understand more , would love to assist you , if you haven't already figured it out.